# Why does nltk word counting differs from word counting using a Regex?

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

### Question

We have two 'versions' of the same text from a txt file (https://www.gutenberg.org/files/2701/old/moby10b.txt):

- `raw_text = f.read()`
- `nltk_text = nltk.Text(nltk.word_tokenize(raw_text))`

What I am missing is why `nltk_text.vocab()['some_word'])` returns a smaller count than `len(re.findall(r'\b(some_word)\b', raw_text)))`.

### Full Code Example

```
import nltk
import re

with open('moby.txt', 'r') as f:
    raw_text = f.read()
nltk_text = nltk.Text(nltk.word_tokenize(moby_raw))

print(nltk_text.vocab()['whale'])                    #prints 782
print(len(re.findall(r'\b(whale)\b', raw_text))      #prints 906
```

Comment: Your "moby_raw" is not defined here.

Comment: @dgg32 moby_raw is in raw_text.

Comment: try with small text so you could count it manually in text and check what you have in `nltk_text`. Maybe it removed some words.

Comment: @furas for cases (small text), it seems there is no difference between the two. If `nltk_text` removed words I would like to know why!

Comment: if you use `raw_text.lower()` then you get different result

Comment: @furas this is expected as there is also the word "Whale" in the text. To clarify, I am interested only in "whale" (lowercase).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run

```
for word in nltk_text.vocab():
    if 'whale' in word.lower():
        print(word)
```

then you see long list of words like

```
whale-ship
whale-lance
whale-fishery
right-whale
sperm-whale
```

which are not counted as `whale`

If you check them with regex then you see it counts them as `whale`

```
print(len(re.findall(r'\b(whale)\b', 'whale-hunter whale-lance whale-fishery right-whale sperm-whale'))) 

# prints 5
```

---

**EDIT:**

Using this code I found few situations when `nltk` and `regex` gives different results

```
import nltk
import re

with open('Pulpit/moby10b.txt') as f:
    raw_text = f.read()

# --- get all `whale` with few chars around (-4, +10)

word_length = len('whale')
words = []

# search first word at position 0
position = raw_text.find('whale', 0)

while position != -1:
    # get word (with few chars around)
    start = position - 4
    end   = position + word_length + 10
    word  = raw_text[start:end]
    # add word to list
    words.append(word)
    # search next word at position `position+1`
    position = raw_text.find('whale', position+1)

# --- test words with nltk and regex

for word in words:

    nltk_text = nltk.Text(nltk.word_tokenize(word))
    number_1 = nltk_text.vocab()['whale']
    number_2 = len(re.findall(r'\b(?<!-)(whale)(?!-)\b', word))
    if number_1 != number_2:
        print(number_1, number_2, word)
        print('-----')
```

Result:

```
1 0 ite whale--did ye m
-----
1 0 ite whale--shirr! s
-----
1 0 erm
whale--squid or
-----
0 1 erm whale's
head em
-----
0 1 the whale's
Decapit
-----
0 1 the whale's
headlon
-----
0 1 the whale's
eyes ha
-----
1 0 EAD whale--even as 
-----
0 1 the whale's
flukes 
-----
1 0 one whale--as a sol
-----
0 1 the whale's
vocabul
-----
1 0 rst
whale--a boy-ha
-----
1 0 the whale--modifyin
-----
```

I shows two situations

1. `whale--` with double `-`

   `nltk` counts it but `regex` doesn't count it.
2. `whale's\nhead` with `\n` between `whale's` and next word
   head

   `nltk` doesn't counts it (but it counts when there is space
   instead of `\n` or when there is space after/before `\n`) but `regex` counts it in every situation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Any idea why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: what do you want to fix ? `whale-ship` means something different then `whale` so NLTK works correctly. And if you want to treat `whale-ship` as two separated words then replace `-` with space - `raw_text = raw_text.replace('-', ' ')`

Comment: you may have to also replace `'s` with space for words `whale's`

Comment: those words indeed caused most of the problem. I updated the regular expression to `\b(?<!-)(whale)(?!-)\b`. Now, it prints 781 which is one less. Any guess why this happens?

Comment: write script which finds all `whale` (not only full words), cut off `whale` with few chars before and after word and then test every string in nltk and regex. You will see which string match in nltk but not in regex.

Comment: I found `'whale--'` with double `-`. `nltk` counts it but `regex` doesn't count it. There is other problem - `whale's\nhead` with `\n` between `whale's` and `head` - `nltk` doesn't counts it (but it counts when there is space instead  of `\n`) but `regex` counts it in every situation - when there is `\n` or space

Comment: It seems these are all the problems! Thank you very much for your time! Please list those problems in your answer so I can accept it :)

Comment: I added problems in answer.

Answer (score 1):

The key reason why this is happening is on account of **tokenization**. A token is not always a word, its an NLP concept that the author will not dive into as of now. If one wants an exact match for a word and not necessarily a token, please use *wordpunct_tokenize* instead of *word_tokenize*. Sample code below.

```
nltk_text = nltk.Text(nltk.word_tokenize(raw_text))
nltk_text2 = nltk.Text(nltk.wordpunct_tokenize(raw_text))
print(nltk_text.vocab()['whale']) #782
print(nltk_text2.vocab()['whale']) #906
print(len(re.findall(r'whale', raw_text))) #906
```

*Suggested further reading* [here](https://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/tokenize.html)

Comment: nice but it seems OP want something different. OP want to create `regex` which gives the same result as `word_tokenize` - `782`. OP doesn't want tokienizer which gives `906`. I'm not sure but maybe OP want to use only `regex` in its final code.